# Switch between windows by title

Tags: windows

Doing Alt-Tab is great, but once you have 20 windows open it can be a nightmare.

Is there any solution that would allow switching between open windows by their title?

The ideal flow would be: Press Alt-Tab, hold Alt, press a few letters from the window title you want to switch to, release Alt, kaboom! :-) Matching on any letters fitting window title, with sorting by closest match.

Comment: this isn't an answer but are you aware that you can do alt-tab then hold alt and use arrow keys.  Also, there is a program called Vista Switcher (it's not just for Vista). it is an alt-tab replacement.. though it's likely not to have the feature you mention. It may still be worth a try.  VirtuaWin is interesting in how it shows loads of windows compactly, though i'm sure it doesn't have the typing feature you ask for.

Comment: Are you attempting to answer your own question with that last sentence? If so, you need to post it below, not within the question.

Comment: Good point CharlieRB - I posted the 'ideal flow' I'd like to see, not an answer.

Comment: @barlop - it shows windows compactly, but you still need to tap the "alt+tab" twenty times to get to the right window...

Comment: @ronszon if win7 is working correctly I think you should never have to hit alt-tab loads of times 'cos you can use arrow keys.. though that said, currently i'm finding arrow keys aren't working within alt-tab and I see no solution to that http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/arrow-keys-close-alt-tab-window-in-win-7/2960c13e-c965-47b9-9baa-8eaba861a3dd

Comment: I also need this feature, they put a "Search" feature in Win-Tab (Win 10) but it is completely useless, it does not search the title of the window. Is there somewhere we can vote for this feature? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not as straightforward as you'd wish, but you may get kind of similar behaviour:
Open Task Manager (<kbd>ctrl-shift-esc</kbd>), then (optional, if not already selected) select `Applications` Tab and then you can start typing to select the app you want; press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open it/bring it onscreen)

Comment: Haha, that's a pretty hack, but if it could be compacted to one operation - would be great. Also, my Task manager is always put to the process details...

Comment: what about this: 
Windows logo key key +T  - Cycle through programs on the taskbar. (they do not say anything about keyboard, but I've checked that if you press the combination the 'bar' becomes active and you can use letters to select groups of programs (and then keys to select a program from group) - just be aware to press win+T and release it as otherwise it maytrigger another function /eg. pressing S will lock the desktop/). Taken from: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-7

Comment: @wmz This is a great hack, however it works only for the 1st letter, which is not ideal. Thanks!